# Does closing/opening a connection violate immutability?

Tags: java, state, immutability

If I have a class I'm striving to make immutable, with a member `private final Connection conn` for example, does performing a `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...)` or `conn.close()` violate the principles of immutability? At the end of the day, the **state** of the `Connection` is in fact changing. And since the **state** of my class is determined by the **state** of its members, does the **state** of my object then not also change?

Comment: Do you really need Connection as a non-static instance field?

Comment: From outside the object, is there any way (using non-private methods) to see a difference depending on the state of the connection? If yes, then your object is mutable. Mutability is about the *observed* state of the object, after creation completes.

Comment: Immutability in Java basically comes down to thread safety, whether a change is visible to another thread (changes within a thread are of course always visible to that thread).  So it seems to violate the spirit of immutability to me (I wouldn't expect an immutable object to be opening and closing database connections) but IO is often thread safe by itself, so you might not technically violate any thread safe/immutability rules by doing so.

Comment: Re. @Andreas 's comment "from the outside.. is there anyway to see a difference.."  Remember that "outside" is not the important point.  It's thread visibility.  So if a second thread calls a method, and that method calls your database connection while a previous thread is still in there, is there any way the two threads will stomp all over each other and return a bad result (remember, a bad result will probably be "seen" by the outside)?  The answer seems "probably" but it's also possible cover all of one's bases and prevent that.  Still, the idea seems like bad practice, regardless.

Comment: @markspace Immutability is not only about thread safety. It's about the object not changing state. If 2 threads call a method and one of them returns "bad" result, then they *observe* different output, and hence prove that object is not immutable. But if a single thread call a method twice and *observe* different output, then it has also proven object to not be immutable. Sure, immutability is a great way to ensure thread safety, not immutability is not only about that.

Comment: An object that holds a connection that can be opened and closed is not immutable.  It's not going to be.  You need state somewhere, and a connection has state.

Answer (score 4):

Right, no way can you call your object immutable if it contains something like that. The connection is stateful.

Embedding a connection inside something Iike that seems like a bad idea for practical reasons. Connections can break or go stale and it’s better to let operations retrieve a new connection from a pool when they need it.

Comment: Interesting. Then [this simple `DBConnection` class](https://pastebin.com/W4MCcS0U) wouldn't be considered immutable. What would be the recommended way then to handle the `Connection` in an immutable way?

Comment: @Answoquest: I don’t think you can (or if you can it’s doubtful it would be worth the trouble). The best you can do is keep it away from things you want to be immutable. Remember SOLID, esp Single Responsibility.

Comment: Interesting, thanks you. In that case, that all being said, is the class that I pastebinned above necessarily bad in any regard?

Comment: @Answoquest: i would guess a new one would have to be created for every different call to it. so there would be a lot of object creation going on.